# Find $f(z)$ s.t $z=0$ is essential singular point for $f(z)$ but not an isolated singular point for $\frac{1}{f(z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

the question is: give an example of a funciton $f(z)$ such that, $z=0$ is an Essential singular point for $f(z)$ and not an isolated singular point for $\frac{1}{f(z)}$

I thought about giving a function that has a sequence of singular points in the points $z=\frac{1}{n}$ but I have no idea how to formulate it. help\hints would be appreciated !

Comment: If it's not isolated, that must mean $f$ has an infinite number zeros in a neighborhood of the origin. Ring any bells?

Comment: You can use $f(z)=\sin(2\pi/z)$. Then $1/f(z)$ has poles at $z=1/n$ as you wanted.

Comment: Thank you Ninad and plop !! the sine function is exactly what i've been looking for